# getting EntityManager from an unmanaged class

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, ejb

How can I get the EntityManager from a class that is not an EJB? Moreover this class isn't managed by the container. Can I get a reference from the JNDI? Is there ANY way?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

First, you'll need to declare a persistence unit/context reference.  If you want to use `@PersistenceUnit(name="jpa/pu", unitName="...")` or `@PersistenceContext(name="jpa/pc", unitName="...")` annotations, these must be placed on an injection-capable class (e.g., on a servlet or EJB class), and if you just want to use them from outside the injection-capable class, you can put them on the class (possibly within `@PersistenceUnits` or `@PersistenceContexts` container annotations if you have several).  Alternatively, you can specify the same metadata in web.xml (or ejb-jar.xml).

Second, you'll need to perform a JNDI lookup using the name declared in the reference.  Using the examples above, this would be something like:

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = (EntityManagerFactory) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env/jpa/pu");
EntityManager em = (EntityManager) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env/jpa/pc");
```

Note that the lookup must be performed within the *context* of the declared references.  For example, if your servlet calls another class that uses JPA, then you'll need to declare the references in web.xml (or annotate a servlet class).  If your servlet calls an EJB that calls another class that uses JPA, then you'll need to declare the references in ejb-jar.xml for that EJB (or annotate the EJB).

Answer (score 0):

```
EntityManager em = (EntityManager) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env/persistence/em");
```

Comment: Already tried it. Returns null because the class is not managed by the container.

Comment: @MikeArgyriou No, it's null because you're specifying incorrect JNDI lookup string.

Comment: A failed lookup shouldn't return null in any case.

Answer (score 0):

```
EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("persistenceUnitName");
EntityManager entityManager =  factory.createEntityManager();
```

I tested it and it works.

[source](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Runtime)

Comment: Note that while this appears to work, the danger in creating a separate EntityManagerFactory is that it will differ from the default factory created and managed by the Container. Therefore things like NamedQueries won't be visible and managed Entities may differ and enable dirty operations.