# How to switch between db in hibernate?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, web-applications

I have two databases defined in my web application. One for fashion and one for sports. Currently Im accessing the sports database. Now that I want to change it to fashion database means how can I do that ? I'm using spring with hibernate. Is there any in-built support for this either in spring or hibernate ?

**EDIT 1:**

I will have a web page where I can choose which database to use and then the changes should get reflected automatically. Is there any way to do it ?

FYI : Both the databases will have the same design. Only the data will be different

Comment: Is your database MySql?

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate specific configuration may differ slightly, but with `JPA` you need to have two `EntityManagerFactories` configured, one for each database. Then you would use either one depending on which database you want to access.

You **can't** do this with a single `EntityManagerFactory` (or the pure Hibernate equivalent).

Comment: Your design is dubious. Why not store everything in the same database, have a `category` to distinguish between fashion and sports. That way you can add more categories if you want to.

Comment: Who's "they"? Tell "them" that it doesn't make sense to have separate databases for essentially the same data.

Comment: Requirement is like each store ( fashion & Sports ) will have a separate database.  Can we do something about it ?

Comment: Yes, deploy the same system twice. That way you have redundancy as well. If sports section goes down, the fashion section still runs.

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18381449/4225763) is an answer to your question. You can simply add a second PersistenceUnit and create a second Factory for your Entity Managers for it.
I hope this helps!
Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Mysql only has one database. It has many schemas (which it calls databases). You can query a table in another schema by prefixing it: schema_name.table_name .