# Hibernate validator causing many to many relationship to not save

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-validator

I have a ManyToMany relationship between User and Role. I have a custom hibernate validation constraint on my roles Set in User.

In a `@PostConstruct` I save the initial roles (ADMIN, USER) to the database using standard JpaRepository from spring-data-jpa. I then create an initial user using the admin role.

If I do not have my custom validation, the association is saved correctly and I see an entry in `user_role` join table. If I have the validation, the user is inserted into the user table, **but without an entry into `user_role` table.** The returned entity has the role in the roles set, but it is not saved into the DB. The code is summarized below. I cannot understand how using the RoleRepo to fetch all of the roles could in any way break the save, but it does.

```
class User {
  @Id
  String username;

  @ValidOption
  @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL //for example}, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
  Set<Role> roles;
}

class Role {
  @Id
  String name;
}

class CustomValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidOption, Object> {
  RoleRepository roleRepo; //injected by spring... have spring factory

  @Override
  public boolean isValid(Object value, ConstraintValidatorContext context){
    roleRepo.findAll() //<-------------- THIS CALL BREAKS THE SAVE
    return true;
  }
}

@Component
class UserCreator {
  RoleRepository roleRepo;
  UserRepo userRepo;

  @PostConstruct
  void setup(){
    Role admin = roleRepo.saveAndFlush(new Role('ADMIN'));
    roleRepo.saveAndFlush(new Role('USER'));

    User user = new User('admin', Collections.singleton(admin));
    userRepo.save(user); //<------ DOES NOT INSERT ADMIN INTO USER_ROLE JOIN TABLE
  }
}
```

This works 100% exactly the way I would expect if I remove the custom validator. It may also work if I don't run this in PostConstruct and schedule it in a different thread, I need to check that.

Project with reproducible failing test case: https://github.com/tjhelmuth/SPR-22533/blob/master/src/test/java/spr22533/bug/BugExample.java

Comment: do you have some output for us? i don't clearly understand "break the save".

Comment: There is no negative output as in an exception. I have bolded the negative output in my description. The user is saved into the "user" table, but not inserted into the user_role join table. My returned entity from the "save" call has the ADMIN role in it, but it is not saved in the DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accessing the `EntityManager` during validation is not guaranteed to work during validation.

Validation happens in "lifecycle callback methods".
For these the following restriction applies (Java Persistence Specification 2.2; Section 3.5.2 Lifecycle Callback Methods):

> In general, the lifecycle method of a portable application should not invoke EntityManager or query operations, access other entity instances, or modify relationships within the same persistence context. A lifecycle callback method may modify the non-relationship state of the entity on which it is invoked.

To make it work, use a separate `EntityManager`, which of course might suffer from seeing a different set of changes since it runs a different transaction.

See also: [Correct way to do an EntityManager query during Hibernate Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18267269/correct-way-to-do-an-entitymanager-query-during-hibernate-validation)

Comment: Okay thank you, my only issue would be I am a big fan of your work with spring data and would like to use my JpaRepository implementations as normal. If I fork a new thread within the validator will I be able to get a new EM and JpaRepository instance?

Comment: Thanks for the kind words. 

Starting a new thread might work but feels hacky. I wonder if one could create a dedicated scope for the validator. Alternatively one could construct the repository programmatically.

Of course depending on what you actually want to do in the validator, just creating a new `EntityManager` and using it directly might be the easier way to go.

If you are interested in exploring the alternatives, please create a new question, because a full answer won't fit in a comment.