# Where should I handle database queries for validation with spring data jpa?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I have recently been working on an API using spring boot with spring-data-jpa. I have been using jsr303 annotations with hibernate validator for validating my dtos in my API requests before mapping them to JPA entity.

I also was using the same hibernate validator annotations on my JPA entity to validate when passing the entity to a spring data jpa repository to save it.

Most of these validations use a spring data jpa repository to validate something like whether the passed in value is in a specific list in the database. I have been told recently however that using an EntityManager during a jpa lifecycle (validation) is not supported, and ran into bugs with it, see: [Hibernate validator causing many to many relationship to not save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55032438/hibernate-validator-causing-many-to-many-relationship-to-not-save)

I have received feedback that it is a "weird" idea to use these annotations to validate an entity in the persistence layer. My question would be, where SHOULD I do the validation of my entity? As I said, I have validation at my rest API layer, but I don't want to just assume I constructed an entity correctly in code unrelated to the rest layer.

One option I was going to try is using the JSR annotations on the entity, but validating them in my service layer methods using @Valid. The problem is the EntityManager will try to validate those annotations anyway and I can't seem to find a way to make it ignore them.

I really don't want to implement all of my validation by hand when jsr303 annotations work well...